# JavaScript methods: Can't stop propagation

Tags: javascript

I have an object literal which represents a page structure of an app. If a certain condition is met, I want to skip a page and go to the next one.

Please take a look at the following code:

```
    var someObj = {
        "page-1": {
            before: function(x){
                switch(x){
                    case true:
                        break;
                    case false:
                        someObj['page-2'].init(); // HERE, I want to skip to the page-2 init() method, **and not go back!**
                        return false;
                        break;
                }
            },              
            init: function(){
                this.before(false);
                alert("This is page 1!"); // I don't want to see this!
            },
        },          
        "page-2": {         
            init: function(){
                alert("this is page 2!"); // After this alert, I want to STOP, and not go back to the page-1 init() method!
                return false;
            },
        },              

    }

    someObj['page-1'].init();
```

I can't work out how to stop after the "This is page 2!" alert - I always get 2 alerts. None of the `return false` work? How can I do this?

Comment: There is no "propagation" here, there's just method calls. The only way to get out is `throw`ing an exception.

Comment: Sorry, yes, wrong terminology. OK - Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `before()` to always return a boolean and make the remainder of the page-1 `init()` method conditional:

```
before: function(x){
    if (!x) {
        someObj['page-2'].init();
    }
    return x;
},
init: function(){
    if (this.before(false)) {
        alert("This is page 1!");
    }
},
```

Comment: This seems most logical. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can either have all your functions pay attention to return values from other functions they call, implementing an "abort" protocol of some kind, or you can throw an exception.

```
    "page-2": {         
        init: function(){
            alert("this is page 2!"); 
            throw new Error("Cease and desist");
        },
    },
```

The choice between the two approaches depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is actually check to see what returns from your before() function and based on that value execute the rest of the init() method, like this:

```
if(this.before(false)){
  do stuff
}else{
  do something else
}
```